# How do I get the column index of parent control of control that sent the routed event?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, routed-events

I have a `UserControl` on my form with a `Button` that when clicked, adds another instance of the `UserControl` or a different `UserControl` in a new row or column. What I'm trying to do is when the `Button` is clicked, find out what column the `UserControl` containing the `Button` is in, and then add the new `UserControl` to that same column. The code for this is below:

```
        ++rowCount;
        int currentColumn = Grid.GetColumn(e.Source as UIElement);
        AnswerNode answerNode = new AnswerNode();
        answerNode.buttonAddQuestionNode.MouseLeftButtonDown += AddQuestionNode_DifferentLevelEvent;
        answerNode.Margin = new Thickness(0, 5, 0, 5);
        RowDefinition gridRowNew = new RowDefinition();
        gridRowNew.Height = new GridLength(70);
        Grid.SetRow(answerNode, rowCount);
        Grid.SetColumn(answerNode, currentColumn);
        MainGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(gridRowNew);
        MainGrid.Children.Add(answerNode);
```

The problem I'm running into is that getting the column index for `e.Source` is resulting in the index of the button within the `UserControl` — in this case `1` — and not the column index of the `UserControl` itself. How would I access the column index of the `UserControl` that is the parent of the `Button` which was clicked?

Comment: There is a lot of code in your question that appears irrelevant to the actual question, while much of the code is missing. Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what you've tried. If `e.Source` is the `Button` object, then it seems likely you're handling the wrong event (i.e. attaching the handler to the `Button` instead of the `UserControl`), but without more context it's not really possible to say for sure what a good answer would be.

Answer (score 0):

Without [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly illustrates the question, showing exactly what you've tried and how you want the event handling to work, it's difficult to know for sure what the best answer would be. That said, from what little code you've provided and your problem description, it sounds like you have subscribed to the event in the wrong control object. Specifically, you have declared your event handler in the `Button` object directly, rather than subscribing to the `Button.Click` event in the `UserControl`.

For a routed event, you can always get the original source of the event, i.e. the control where the event was initially signaled via the `RoutedEventArgs.OriginalSource` property. The `RoutedEventArgs.Source` property in turn will provide the reference to the control object to which the event has been routed and is *currently* handling the event. If you want to handle the event as seen by the `UserControl` object, then you need to subscribe to the event from the `UserControl` object, not the `Button` object.

Here is a short, complete code example that illustrates the basic technique:

### XAML:

#### UserControl1.xaml

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="TestSO33441926RoutedEvent.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition/>
      <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Click here: "/>
    <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Click me!" Grid.Column="1"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Click="Button_Click"/>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

#### MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="TestSO33441926RoutedEvent.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:l="clr-namespace:TestSO33441926RoutedEvent"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Grid x:Name="grid1">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition/>
      <ColumnDefinition/>
      <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Text="MainWindow column 1"/>
    <TextBlock Text="MainWindow column 2" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <l:UserControl1 x:Name="userControl1" Grid.Column="2"
                    Button.Click="UserControl1_Click"/>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

### C#:

#### UserControl1.xaml.cs

```cs
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        App.ReportClick((FrameworkElement)e.Source);
    }
}
```

#### MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void UserControl1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        App.ReportClick((FrameworkElement)e.Source);
    }
}
```

#### App.xaml.cs

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public static void ReportClick(
        FrameworkElement frameworkElement, [CallerMemberName]string callerName = null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(
            "Caller name: \"" + callerName + "\"\n" +
            "Sender name: \"" + frameworkElement.Name + "\"\n" +
            "Sender column: " + Grid.GetColumn(frameworkElement));
    }
}
```

Since neither event handler sets `RoutedEventArgs.Handled` to `true`, the event will be sent to each handler in turn, starting with the original source of the event and moving up the visual object graph to each parent in turn.

As such, you can see that when the `ReportClick()` method is called by each event handler, the `e.Source` object is different in each event handler, depending on where that handler was subscribed.

For your own question, the key is here, in the `MainWindow.xaml` source code:

```
    <l:UserControl1 x:Name="userControl1" Grid.Column="2"
                    Button.Click="UserControl1_Click"/>
```

Note that the `Button.Click` event is the one being subscribed, but that the code is subscribing *from the `UserControl1` object*. This has the result that the event handler `void UserControl1_Click(object, RoutedEventArgs)` is called with the `UserControl1` object as the sender and source of the event.

Thus, when the column index of the sender of the event is retrieved by calling `Grid.GetColumn(UIElement)`, the column index of the `UserControl1` object is returned, not the column index of the original source of the event (i.e. the `Button` object that was actually clicked).

*As an aside: in the bit of code your posts shows, there seems to be a fair amount of code-behind that is probably better-implemented as XAML declarations. Naturally, just about anything you can do in XAML, you can also accomplish in code-behind. But that doesn't mean it's a good idea. Addressing that defect in your code is not likely to relate directly to the question you're asking, nor would changing the implementation in that way fix the problem. But you should definitely consider seriously following the WPF/XAML paradigm more closely and put as much of your implementation in XAML as you can.*